# how to create paging with multi different table?

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have 3 table with no association with other. There are post,place and event.
Now I want to make paging with my table sort by date. How can I get limit this paging into 10 items per page and when I click more, the data, will show continue like twitter paging?

example:

```
1.post
2.place
3.post
4.post
5.place
6.event
7.place
8.post
9.post
10.post
<more>
```

thanks for any help....
and sorry for my english.. :)

Comment: what about creating a 4th table with the id's and dates of those entries?

Comment: seems good..I will try this first..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just create a view and use UNION
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

```
(SELECT post, date FROM post)
UNION
(SELECT place, date FROM post)
UNION
(SELECT event, date FROM event)
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 0,10;
```

You can use PHP or Javascript to make the pages of 10

JQuery paging plugins
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/paging